# How to put time python in a certain url

Tags: python, time

I want to do the following:

```
requestor = UrlRequestor("http://www.myurl.com/question?timestamp=", {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Cookie' : self.EASW_KEY + ";", 'X-UT-SID' :self.XUT_SID}, 'answer=' + self.securityHash)
requestor.open()
self.FUTPHISHING = requestor.getHeader('Set-Cookie').split(';')[0]
```

Right after timestamp, I would like to have the local time in this format: 1355002344943

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the time in that format from the [time](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) module. Specifically I'd do it this way

```
import time

timeurl = "http://www.myurl.com/question?timestamp=%s" % time.time()
requestor = UrlRequestor(timeurl, {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',      'Cookie' : self.EASW_KEY + ";", 'X-UT-SID' :self.XUT_SID}, 'answer=' + self.securityHash)
requestor.open()
self.FUTPHISHING = requestor.getHeader('Set-Cookie').split(';')[0]
```

time.time() returns a float, so if it doesn't like that level of precision you can do

```
timeurl = "http://www.myurl.com/question?timestamp=%s" % int(time.time())
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but is the $s required?

Comment: You could also do `"http://www.myurl.com/question?timestamp={}".format(time.time())` which is the new way of string formatting in Python -- these are the two ways to do this, however.

Comment: Sam makes a good point, the .format() is the preferred way. There's a good discussion of it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format)

Comment: Thanks guys it was  really helpful, but do I really need to put timeurl = before I mean to creat a new variable?

Comment: @user203558: Separate variables for the timestamp or the url are not necessary, but they can help reduce the `requestor` line's length. In general it's a good practice to avoid lines that can't all fit on your editor's screen at once.

Answer (score 1):

That timestamp looks to be based off of [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (e.g. seconds since Jan 1 1970), but it has three more digits. Probably it is in milliseconds, not seconds. To replicate it, I suggest doing:

```
import time

timestamp = int(time.time()*1000)
url = "http://www.myurl.com/question?timestamp=%d" % timestamp
```

You could also simply concatenate the timestamp onto the URL, if you don't want to do string formatting:

```
url = "http://www.myurl.com/question?timestamp=" + str(timestamp)
```